# Indentation of character from .dat file in pandas fwf fuction

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered the following issue when reading a dat file with the fwf function of pandas (on a python 3.11 enviroment)

the file looks like that

1015OYMAPA01xxxxxxxxxJOHN DOE

1015OYMAPA01yyyyyyyyyLEONARDO DI CAPRIO

1015OYMAPA01zzzzzzzzzMARGOT ROBBIE

and I import it with the following code line

```
 df =pd.read_fwf(filename.dat , colspecs=[(4,12), (12, 21), (21,100)], names= ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Full Name'])
```

the displayed table look fine for every line but the first one in the dat file, meaning that I observe the following

| Col1 | Col2 | Full Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5OYMAPA0 | 1xxxxxxxx | xJOHN DOE |
| OYMAPA01 | yyyyyyyyy | LEONARDO DI CAPRIO |
| OYMAPA01 | zzzzzzzzz | MARGOT ROBBIE |

I do not understand what am I doing wrong, especially because the desired output is there for every column but the first one which gets shifted by one character.

Could it depend on pandas? or could be some encoding problem that I am not aware of?

Thanks to everyone who is willing to participate.

Giacomo

Answer (score 0):

Does your file include headers? According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) if you're using the `names` argument with a file that doesn't have headers you need to specify `header=None`:

```py
 df =pd.read_fwf(filename.dat , colspecs=[(4,12), (12, 21), (21,100)], names= ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Full Name'], header=None)
```

I can't currently try this myself to see if it works, but it seems like this might cause the misalignment in the first row.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I added the ```header=None```spec but unfortunately the result is the same